# Transfer rate for connecting multiple Firewire cables from external hard drive

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, firewire

What happens when I connect 2 Firewire cables from an external hard drive to a PC? Will the transfer rate doubles?

Reason for asking:
Throughput rate from our server to the external hard drive is too slow for backups using USB 2.0 interface. I'm asking this question because I want to purchase a Firewire PCI card with multiple Firewire interfaces. Our external hard drive got 2 firewire interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second port is for daisy chaining multiple Firewire drives and won't work to double your throughput.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it will double. It may not even be recognised on the computer.

On the other hand, Firewire 800 is full duplex and twice as fast as USB 2.0 in any event. Why not just try with one cable?

Comment: Yes, Firewire is faster than USB, but I'm just asking since our external harddrive got 1 USB & 2 Firewire interfaces.

Comment: I understand your question, but I honestly don't think it will work, hence "It may not even be recognised on the computer".

Comment: It will not work.  The second interface is for daisy-chaining devices not for connecting two lines to the same computer.